# Changing route with ui-router skipping resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in my angular app.
I define the routing like this:

```
angular.module('app.product', [])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('product', {
      url: '/product/:product_id',
      templateUrl: 'partial/product',
      controller: 'productCtrl',
      resolve: {
        product: ['$http', '$stateParams',
          function($http, $stateParams) {
            return $http.get('/api/product/' + $stateParams.product_id);
          }]
      }
    })
}])
```

At some point, I manually change the route on the client side using `$state.go('product')`. Here I already have the `product` data on the client side so there is no need for an extra `$http` request.

What is the best way to pass the data in the `$state.go` call and let ui-router know there is no need to make this request?

Should I build a service to handle this?

Comment: So you want some kind of caching? You should use a service/factory for this and check all caching relevant information there. I think angular http already supports caching, check it out.

Comment: Put that code in a service, not in the resolve of your controller, then you can keep a local copy pf that data and when it's empty make a serer call, otherwise return it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a service (something like the code below). Just note this is off the top of my head.

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('product', {
            url: '/product/:product_id',
            templateUrl: 'partial/product',
            controller: 'productCtrl',
            resolve: {
                product: ['ProductCache', '$stateParams',
                function(ProductCache, $stateParams) {
                    return ProductCache.getProduct($stateParams.product_id);
                }]
            }
        });
}])
.factory('ProductCache', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var cache = [];
    return {
        getProduct: function(id) {
            // return the product if available, otherwise from the api
            if(!cache[id]){
                return $http.get('/api/product/' + id, function(result){
                    cache[id] = result.product; // or however your api return is structured
                    return cache[id];
                });
            }else{
                // use .when() to ensure a promise is returned to the resolve function
                return $q.when(cache[id]);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```